# I'm having doubts about solving a problem involving fractions.

Tags: combinatorics

I would like to know if my way of solving the problem is correct. I'm starting to solve math problems, but I still have doubts about how I solve the problems, and I really don't know if my solution is correct, I'd like someone to tell me if it's correct.

**Question**

In the context of recreational mathematics, using various teaching materials to motivate her students, a teacher organized a game with a modified type of deck. At the beginning of the game, a card from the deck on the table is turned over and each player receives nine cards in their hands. You want to form pairs of cards, the first card being the board card and the second a card in the player's hand, which has a value equivalent to that described on the board card. The object of the game is to see which player gets the most pairs. Once the game is started, the face card on the table and the cards in a player's hand are as shown in the diagram:

[image]

According to the rules of the game, how many cards in this hand
player can pair the board card?

a) 9
b) 7
c) 5
d) 4
e) 3

What I tried:

At the beginning of the game, a card on the table is turned over. And each player has 9 cards in hand.
The objective of the game is to see which players get the highest number of pairs, and by pairs, I understand that they are cards with the same value.

According to the rules of the game, how many cards in this hand
player can pair the board card?

The question is clear: *which of the 9 cards in the player's hand has the same value as the card on the board.*

To find out which one has the same value as the card on the table, I turned them all into percentages.

Table card => 75% (because 6/8 . 100 = 600/8 = 75%)
I see that the cards in the hand, there are 75%(already in percentage) and 0.75(x100 => 75%), that is, they are two cards that can form a pair with the board card. Among the other cards, only one is equal to 75%, which is the one with the *3/4* fraction. 
I came to this conclusion by multiplying the numerator by 100 and dividing by 4, turning it into a percentage. However, if you look closely at this card, you can see that it has the same value as the card on the board, with the only difference that it was simplified (divided) by 2.

Thus, 3 cards from the player's hand can be paired with the card on the board, as they have the same value.

I'm not sure my line of reasoning is correct, I would like someone to tell me if I am correct and if there is any easier way to get to the answer (I say this because I am used to transforming fractions to percentages in order to find the same percentage , which makes it clear to me that fractions have the same value).

**Ignore the plural in the image caption (table cards). It is just one card.**

Comment: Yes, you're correct that three cards in the player's hand can be paired with the table card, and you have correctly identified which three cards those are.

Comment: @RobertShore Thanks!